# How to give Installer options from msiexec command

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I want to install my msi file using msiexec command. However using the UI,  I get to choose some things during the install. How can I give these options using the msiexec command

This is what i get on double clicking the installer
[Installer Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLDnr.png)

[Installer Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrPad.png)

[On selecting an option in step 2 i get a textbox to give new location for my installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk58J.png)

I cant understand how to give these options using msiexec.
On doing a

```
 msiexec.exe /i "path\myinstaller.win-amd64.msi" /L*V "path\mylogfile.log"
```

The installer UI pops up.
But I want my msiexec command to do everything for me.
I tried using the `/quiet` option and it does not pop open the installer UI but also it does not install my msi package.

So, how can i give my UI options using just the msiexec command

Comment: Have a look at the [Microsoft Standard Installer Command-Line Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/standard-installer-command-line-options). Especially, use the `/help` switch to see what else you could have the msi installer do

Comment: If the installer does not run quietly, it either has a bug or it expects special arguments for quiet mode. Some installers require something like `ACCEPT_EULA=1`, but this is different for each installer.

Comment: I would suggest get Orca, open the MSI and look at the Property table to see what values you could set. Without the MSI file it's hard to advise.